# backpack for laravel Add Colum from related table

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have table 3 tables, equipment(ID, name) 
 parameters(ID, name) and the pivot table equipment_parameter(equipment_id, parameter_id) , on my "Equipment" list view i need to add a column with the name of the parameter so i need to retrieve name from the Parameter table.

Equipment Model:

```
 public function parametros(){

   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parametro','equipo_parametro','equipo_id',
                             'parametro_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Parameter model:

```
public function equipos(){

   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipo','equipo_parametro','parametro_id',
                               'equipo_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

i added this on equipmentCrudcontroller ,but have had no success.

```
  $this->crud->addColumn([  // Select
    'label' => 'Parametro',
    'type' => 'select2',
    'name' => 'equipo_id', // the db column for the foreign key 
 (not sure here since equipment foreign key is on pivot table????)
    'entity' => 'parametros', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'nombre', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'model' => "App\Parametro" // (doubt, there's a pivot table inbetween???) foreign key model
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a column and have already run the previous migration you can create a new migration `php artisan make:migration update_equipment_table` inside of that, you can then do something like this

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('column');
});
```

then rerun migrations `php artisan migrate` this will add the new column to your table.

Comment: not exactly, the column exists in another table, I found the solution, instead of using 'type' => 'select2', one must use select_multiple so now it can show the name in another table